# Is it possible to share a common 0VDC (negative) between three DC switch mode power supplies - when two of them are in series?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, series, negative

I have a system that needs a 96VDC and 12VDC feed to operate.
I have a pair of Meanwell RSP-3000-48 power supplies tied together in parallel to supply 96V and a single Meanwell HLG-240-12 supplying 12VDC.
I'd like to run a 3 core cable and powerCON connector to each supplied device but that means I'd need to share a 0VDC/Negative line.
I'm getting a whole load of mixed messages from the supplier so figured I'd ask here.
I've done this plenty of times in the past with no issues. Only difference here (as far as I understand) is the pair of 48V power supplies working in series.
All PSUs are isolated (from ground).
All three will be powered from seperate phases.

See hastily drawn google draw diagram below for (some) clarity.

Any feedback would be very welcome.

Thanks,

Dion.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is your 3core cable and powercon connectors in your diagram? Why mention the AC side? Be it single phase or 3 phase makes no difference to your question.

Comment: @Kartman Three core not shown but would be carrying the +96VDC, +12VDC and common 0VDC. Agree, single or multiphase shouldn't matter but threw it in there to provide the most complete picture possible.

Comment: Taken at face value, there is no question - what you describe should work but a schematic would clear any doubt. Currently you mention a cable and a connector that is not shown so you’re asking us to guess.

Comment: You can't share a common 0V between two supplies in series but that's not what you're trying to do anyway. Your left hand supply has no 0V connection.

Comment: @Finbarr the LHS power supply in series with the middle one. I.e the +48V comes out of the middle supply into the negative input of the LHS supply. Two 48V supplies series'd together to output 96VDC across the two.

Comment: @Kartman thanks for your input. Have updated the drawing with the connector. Will get a schematic whipped up today.

Comment: I don’t see a problem in terms of the connections. What I would be concerned about is electrical safety. 96V can kill you. There are probably specific wiring requirements you’ll need to comply with. It might be easier and safer just to distribute mains.